# How to Convert String to List<String> in Java Without using Jackson Api

Tags: java, json, list, arraylist

I need to convert String to List in Java without using Jackson Api.
My String is like

```
String abc = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]";
```

I want it to convert into List.

I already have `net.sf.json` and `org.json.simple` imported.

I can not use Jackson API but is there any other way to do this instead using split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `org.json.simple` you can use `JSONParser` to parse the JSON

```
String abc = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(abc);
```

Comment: ... and `obj` will be a `JSONArray`, which can then be converted to a Java List.

Comment: This way worked for both cases`String abc = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]";` and `String abc = request.getParameter("str"); //Where str is json string ["A","B","C"]`

Comment: @dPatel1582 this is the same case, escaping `"` in String literal doesn't change the content of the String

Answer (score 1):

In case you have only given json string format `["A","B","C"]` then you can manually parse it:

```
public static List<String> parse(String str) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    int pos = str.indexOf('[') + 1;

    while ((pos = str.indexOf('"', pos)) >= 0) {
        int beginIndex = pos + 1;
        int endIndex = str.indexOf('"', beginIndex);
        res.add(str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
        pos = endIndex + 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```